# PHP: How to prevent url from being converted to HTML entities when using DOMDocument loadHTML

Tags: php, libxml2

I have the code below:

```php
$html = '<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><p>Hello <a href="https://www.example.com?<%= email%>">world</a></p></body></html>';
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
print_r($doc->saveHTML());
```

It prints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><p>Hello <a href="https://www.example.com?&lt;%=%20email%&gt;">world</a></p></body></html>
```

But I need to keep the URL as it is in the href attribute: https://www.example.com?<%= email%>
How to prevent the loadHTML to convert it to https://www.example.com?<%=%20email%&gt; ?

thanks

Comment: no, use safe placeholders instead

Comment: OK. So I will need to search for href attributes with a regexp and decode HTML entities.